# Implement multiple filters using Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list lets's say 'ProductList'

I have a filter bar with tiltes 'Color' and 'Shape' with toggle buttons Red, green, square and round.

Color:
Red     Green

Shape:
Square  Round

**1st category - Color**

If I click red, the 'ProductList' must be filtered for Red color.

`firstFilteredList = ProductList.where((p) => p.color == "red");`

Now if I click green, the 'ProductList' must be filtered for Red and Green color.

`firstFilteredList = ProductList.where((p) => p.color == "red" || p.color == "green");`

**2st category - Shape**

Now if I click square, the 'firstFilteredList' must be filtered for square shape.

`secondFilteredList = firstFilteredList.where((p) => p.shape == "square");`

Now if I click round, the 'firstFilteredList' must be filtered for square and round shape.

`secondFilteredList = firstFilteredList.where((p) => p.shape == "square" || p.shape == "round");`

I need to remove those filters if the button is toggled off.

I've just mentioned two filter categories - Color and shape, for the sake of simplicity. There may be 6-7 filter categories. So, the solution has to be scalable.

Can someone help me solve this?

Edit:
ProductList is a element of CategorizedProduct. I have to return List.

```
class CategorizedProduct {
  String id;
  String title;
  List<Product> product;
  String selectedVariant;
}

class Product {
  String color;
  String id;
  bool shapeRectangle;
  bool shapeRound;
  bool shapeSquare;
}
```

Comment: It is kind of checkbox. So user can select any number of shapes and colors from the list. Is it?

Comment: @Rajesh Yes....

Comment: @pskink Could you please elaborate? I couldn't understand.

Comment: Do you have any code at all for this right now? If so please show it

Comment: Show your ProductList class.... help us help you

Comment: @lenz I've updated the code with the class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put your queries in a list than perform `contains()`.

Here is a Dart example that does it.

```
enum ProductColor { RED, GREEN, BLUE }

enum Weight { HEAVY, NORMAL, LIGHT }

enum Shape { SQUARE, ROUND, TRIANGLE }

class Product {
  final String name;
  final ProductColor color;
  final Weight weight;
  final Shape shape;
  Product(this.name, this.color, this.weight, this.shape);
  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$name $color $weight $shape';
  }
}

class Query {
  final List<ProductColor> color;
  final List<Weight> weight;
  final List<Shape> shape;

  Query({this.color, this.weight, this.shape});
}

List<Product> filter(List<Product> products, Query query) {
  return products
      .where((product) =>
          (query.color == null || query.color.contains(product.color)) &&
          (query.weight == null || query.weight.contains(product.weight)) &&
          (query.shape == null || query.shape.contains(product.shape)))
      .toList();
}

void main() {
  List<Product> _productList = [
    Product("P1", ProductColor.BLUE, Weight.HEAVY, Shape.TRIANGLE),
    Product("P2", ProductColor.GREEN, Weight.NORMAL, Shape.ROUND),
    Product("P3", ProductColor.RED, Weight.LIGHT, Shape.ROUND),
    Product("P4", ProductColor.GREEN, Weight.NORMAL, Shape.SQUARE),
  ];

  Query _query = Query(color: [ProductColor.GREEN], shape: [Shape.ROUND]);

  List<Product> results = filter(_productList, _query);
  results.forEach(print);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `onPressed()` for your filter selections, with a boolean for on or off (filter selected or not). Something like this:

```
//red color filter button 
...
onPressed(
  redFilter = !redFilter; //on if off, off if on...
)
```

Then you can use a list of boolean

```
bool redFilter = false; 
bool greenFilter = false;
bool squareFilter = false;
bool roundFilter = false;

List<bool> filters = [redFilter, greenFilter, squareFilter, roundFilter];
```